# How do i sum different column to get total in array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a input form that look like this:

```
  <form action="payment-code.php" method="POST">
      <tbody>
      <?php  
        $query = "SELECT * FROM staffs ";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0)
         {
          foreach($query_run as $row)
          {
           ?>
           <tr>
             <td>
              <?=$row['staff_id']; ?>
              <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?=$row['staff_id']; ?>">
             </td>
             <td>
                <input type="text" name="salary[]">
             </td>
             <td><input type="text" name="extra_fee[]">
             </td>
             <td><input type="text" name="Bonus[]"></td>
           </tr>
             <?php
                  }
               }
              ?>
               <button type="submit" name="save_payment">Save payment</button>
           </tbody>
     </form>
```

And after fill that form, i want to sum 3 different input values ( salary, extra_fee and Bonus ) to get total_amount that look like the example i put below:

```
id   salary    bonus    extra_fee    total_amount
1     120       10         20         150 
2     110       5          10         125
3     115       4          9          128
4     100       12         10         122 
5     90        10         10         110
6     123        5         10         138
```

I try this code and it does not work. Do you have any other ideas that can acheive this?

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['save_payment']))
    {   
      $id = $_POST['staff_id'];
      $salary = $_POST['salary'];
      $totalfee = $_POST['extra_fee'];
      $totalbonus = $_POST['Bonus'];
      $total_payment = $salary + $totalfee + $totalbonus;
            
     foreach ($staff_id as $key => $value){
    $query = "INSERT INTO payments(staff_id, payment_amount) VALUES ('".$value ."', '".$staff_id[$key]. "', '". $total_payment[$key]."')";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
     }
   
    ?>
```

Please help me since i have struggle with this quite awhile

Comment: Firstly, you can do this with SQL triggers (update total_amount column on these 3 columns update), but it's not a good idea to do any logical operations in a database. It only stores data, you should calculate sum on a server side with PHP, so total_amount column will be uselsess

Answer (score 0):

> Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174).
> Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
> You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
> in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

So I fixed that also

Then all you need to do is do the calulation inside the loop using `$_POST['id]` as the array to loop over and the key of that array to address the others.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['save_payment'])) {   
            
    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $val){
        // do the calc here
        $total_payment = $_POST['salary'][$key] +
                         $_POST['extra_fee'][$key] + 
                         $_POST['Bonus'][$key];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO payments (staff_id, payment_amount) VALUES (?,?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('is', $_POST['id'][$key], $total_payment);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It seems a little strange that you dont store the other data?